# How to create a county map with select counties highlighted?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to highlight select counties on a map of North Dekoda. How would I go about doing this? I have gotten this far so far.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)

county_df <- map_data('county')                          # mappings of counties by state
countyMap <- subset(county_df, region=="north dakota")   # subset just for NYS
countyMap$county <- countyMap$subregion

cnames <- aggregate(cbind(long, lat) ~ subregion, data=countyMap, FUN=mean)

ggplot(countyMap, aes(long, lat)) +  
  geom_polygon(aes(group=group), colour='black', fill=NA) +
  geom_text(data=cnames, aes(long, lat, label = subregion), size=3) +
  coord_map()
```

I would like to highlight the following counties.

```
countynames <- c("Adams",   "Billings", "Bottineau", "Bowman", "Burke",
                 "Divide", "Dunn", "Golden Valley", "Hettinger", "McHenry",
                 "McKenzie", "McLean", "Mercer", "Mountrail", "Renville", 
                 "Slope", "Stark", "Ward", "Williams")
```

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate suggestion, using a North Dakota shapefile so you can get the actual county centroids (also uses some other—some new—packages):

```
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
library(ggthemes)

URL <- "https://ago-item-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/db3ecc5c05434129b569dacf4ca86dcb/ND_counties.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLEZ6UDU5TV4KMBQ&Expires=1453068721&Signature=j8uFQr%2Bcx6f6%2BM6r4eROS6hxow8%3D"
fil <- "nd_counties.zip"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)

fils <- unzip(fil)
shp <- grep("shp$", fils, value=TRUE)

nd <- readOGR(shp, ogrListLayers(shp)[1])

nd_map <- fortify(nd, region="NAME")

nd_proj <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=46.27420257144498 +lat_2=48.669084154799016 +lon_0=-100.30517578125"

cty_labs <- data.frame(gCentroid(nd, byid=TRUE),
                       label=nd$NAME, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

county_names <- data.frame(
  id=c("Adams", "Billings", "Bottineau", "Bowman", "Burke",
       "Divide", "Dunn", "Golden Valley", "Hettinger", "McHenry",
       "McKenzie", "McLean", "Mercer", "Mountrail", "Renville", 
       "Slope", "Stark", "Ward", "Williams"))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=nd_map, data=nd_map,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                    color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_map(map=nd_map, data=county_names,
                    aes(map_id=id), 
                    color="steelblue", size=1, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_label(data=cty_labs, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label), 
                      size=2)
gg <- gg + coord_proj(nd_proj)
gg <- gg + theme_map()
gg
```

You can tweak `color` and `fill` to highlight as necessary.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I really like this map but I'm having problems getting the code to work.  I'm getting an error at this point: nd_map <- fortify(nd, region="NAME")
Error: isTRUE(gpclibPermitStatus()) is not TRUE

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid. I just re-installed the associated packages and it works now. :) Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

here is something to help you started. Just create a subset and then add a second geom_polygon() expression. Just double-check your typos (Capital vs lower case)

```
countynames<-c("adams", "billings")
countyMap_sb <- countyMap %>% filter(county %in% countynames)
ggplot(countyMap, aes(long, lat)) +  
    geom_polygon(aes(group=group), colour='black', fill=NA) +
    geom_text(data=cnames, aes(long, lat, label = subregion), size=3) +
    coord_map() + geom_polygon(data=countyMap_sb, aes(group=group), colour='red', fill='red')
```

[image]

and if you want to use different colors for your polygons, you can add fill and color to aes() and set the colors you want with scale_fill_manual() expression.

```
ggplot(countyMap, aes(long, lat)) +  
    geom_polygon(aes(group=group), colour='black', fill=NA) +
    geom_text(data=cnames, aes(long, lat, label = subregion), size=3) +
    coord_map() + geom_polygon(data=countyMap_sb, aes(group=group, colour=county, fill=county)) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("green", "yellow"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by passing an alternative `fill` option in `aes()` like so:

```
# assign colors to counties (red if in countynames, NA if not) 
counties <- levels(factor(countyMap$county))
cols <- rep(NA, length(counties))
cols[counties %in% tolower(countynames)] <- "red"

ggplot(countyMap, aes(long, lat)) +  
geom_polygon(aes(group=group, fill = factor(county)), colour='black') +
geom_text(data=cnames, aes(long, lat, label = subregion), size=3) +
scale_fill_manual(values = cols, guide = F) +
coord_map()
```